# Best way to automatically reconnect to Wifi? NetworkManager?

Tags: networking, wifi, wireless, networkmanager

I have a Raspberry Pi4 24h connected to the internet via Wifi. Sometimes, I think due some signal loss, it don't reconnect until I reboot it.

I've already tried to run a script that automatically monitor the wifi connection and run *sudo systemctl restart networking.service* but it didn't solve my issue.

So, is there any benefit if I install the **NetworkManager** on Rpi? Can it reconnect to wifi networks or another feature that can help?

I'm running Raspbian Buster.

Comment: @Dougie How on earth is an answer based on Wheezy a duplicate of a Question on a (presumably) current OS?

Comment: @Milliways because the basic principle is identical. Ping something, restart networking when the ping fails.

Comment: Please note l didn't vote to close as duplicate (because it isn't) but because you haven't supplied any details

Comment: This is NOT duplicated. If you read this another post you will see that it's talking about how to restart wifi when *using a dongle adapter". I want to know how to restart the default system, without an external adaptor.

Answer (score 1):

I have several Pi's that run 24/7 and they will automatically reconnect when the wifi is available (I deliberately have my wifi networks turn off at night when there is no need for them to be on). I have found the below to be 100% reliable. I am using static IP on my Pi's but it should work fine with DHCP as well:

```
sudo nano /usr/local/bin/checkwifi.sh
```

Enter this code to restart network (change 192.168.1.1 for an IP address that you expect to always be available, typically your internet router):

```
ping -c4 192.168.1.1 > /dev/null
 
if [ $? != 0 ] 
then
  echo "No network connection, restarting wlan0"
  /sbin/ifdown 'wlan0'
  sleep 5
  /sbin/ifup --force 'wlan0'
fi
```

You need schedule this to run regularly. I chose every five minutes:

```
crontab -e
```

Add:

```
*/5 * * * * /usr/bin/sudo -H /usr/local/bin/checkwifi.sh >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

Comment: I thought ifup / if down where being depreciated in favour of iwconfig and ifconfig as the ifup/down only read the etc/network/interfaces file as they are part of the Network Manager software stack?  Note - this is based on my memory and that can be iffy on a good day :-)

Comment: I have no idea if they are being deprecated - I set it up over three years ago and it's been good since then. It may be that some tweaks need to be made for the current build of Raspbian. While I have started from scratch since then and not had an issue, I tend not to keep the base code up to date (they work so if it ain't broke, I don't want to break it with an update!)

Comment: This will do **NOTHING** on a properly configured *Raspberry Pi OS* using default networking.

Comment: Yeah, @Andyroo and Petec are right... I've tried here and both ifdown and ifup does nothing. They are depreciated. See [this thread](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=213550) for more information...

Answer (score 0):

The default `dhcpcd` is reliable and will automatically connect if correctly configured. See [How to set up networking/WiFi](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/37921/8697)

*Raspberry Pi OS* **DOES NOT** use `networking.service` - unless you misconfigure it.

You can use NetworkManager, but it is difficult to configure manually, and the GUI networking tool in Raspbian won't work. It is  no more reliable than `dhcpcd`. In addition it needs to be re-configured for each Pi - you can't simply swap SD Cards.

Comment: I can see on the link you provide the following: "Restart network via sudo service networking restart". Isn't the same as "restart networking.service"?

Comment: @ViníciusValente If you read the full post you will see I DO NOT recommend static IP, and for those that do to use dhcpcd.

Comment: I'm not using Static IP. I have internet connection with RPi default configuration. I'm just looking for a better way to reset if it gets down. According with this link, maybe a "sudo systemctl stop dhcpcd && sudo systemctl start dhcpcd" can help to "refresh" the device connection?

Comment: Instead of using two commands you can use `sudo systemctl restart dhcpcd.service`.